# ディレクトリを取得すると、場合によっては、スラッシュとバックスラッシュが入り混じるのはどうしてでしょうか？

Tags: python, python3, windows-10, pyqt, pyside

```
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore
import sys
import os

class DirectoryPrinter(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(DirectoryPrinter,self).__init__(parent=None)

        self.filedialog_pushbutton = QtGui.QPushButton("filedialog",self)
        self.connect(self.filedialog_pushbutton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.filename_getter)

    def filename_getter(self):
        print("os.getcwd()から得られたディレクトリです。",os.getcwd())
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"ファイルを選択",os.path.expanduser("~"))[0]
        print("QFileDialogから得られたFileDialogの名前です。",filename)


def main():
    try:
        QtGui.QApplication([])
    except Exception as e:
        print(22,e)
    directoryprinter = DirectoryPrinter()
    directoryprinter.show()

    sys.exit(QtGui.QApplication.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**結果**

```
os.getcwd()から得られたディレクトリです。 J:\
QFileDialogから得られたディレクトリです。 C:/Users/*******/hello.py
```

スラッシュが全く逆になる現象です。
気になるようだったら、(というかこの現象のせいで、ファイルの正確なディレクトリが取得できない問題に当たりました。)`replace`メソッドを行えば改善しますけれども・・・。
どうしてこんな現象がおきるのでしょうか？
パイソンにも右利きと左利きがあるのでしょうか。OSによって違うのでしょうか。
また、皆様の環境ではどのようになりますか？

Comment: 「入り混じる」と書かれていますが、実際には呼び出したメソッドごとで結果に含まれるディレクトリの区切り文字はそれぞれ統一されているわけですよね？

Comment: `os.getcwd()`はOS本来の機能を呼び出しているからだと思いますが(Windowsは`cd`、Linuxは`pwd`)、参考までに、Linuxで実行した場合には結果のディレクトリ区切り文字は`/`となりました。

Comment: @cubick だと思います。`QFileDialog`が逆のスラッシュをとっちゃっているように思います。だから、`QFileDialog`と、`os.getcwd()`を`os.path.join`などで合わせてしまい、それをファイルに収めた後で、安心して取り出すと裏切られます。だから、`QFileDialog`で取得した`path`を混ぜちゃいけないのだと思います。

Comment: @cubick ありがとうございます。Linuxは"/"という事は、普通のスラッシュですね。`PySide`は、そこだけLinux基準なのでしょうか。すでに最初から"/"でコンプリートしているように見えるので、開発側のバグかもしれません。

Comment: 参考: [How to get the window style path using getExistingDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10303933)

Comment: @metropolis おお。これは既に私と同じ問題に当たった人の問題ですね。なぜか？と理由を聞いている点だけでなんとか違う質問になっているということでしょうか。いずれにせよ、普通の現象なのだという事が確認できてよかったです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Qt` は同一のソースコードを OS によらず動かすためのものなので `Qt` 内の「パス」表記は `Linux` ベースのスラッシュ区切りを使います (Windows/Linux によらず) 。

`os.getcwd` は実行する OS に固有の「パス」を取得するものなので `print os.getcwd()` の結果は
- python 2.7.5@hppa2.0w-hp-hpux11.11 上では `/home/john/tmp`
- python 2.7.3@i686-pc-cygwin 上では `/cygdrive/c/CYGWIN/HOME/john/tmp`
- python 2.7.14@x86_64-pc-cygwin 上では `/home/john/tmp`
となりました。 Windows 上でも Linux っぽい機能を使うための cygwin では python もスラッシュ区切りを使うということのようです。

`Qt` 上でパスを扱う上ではパス区切りはスラッシュに統一すればよいです。
パスの取得には `Qt` の機能だけを使わないとはまります。混ぜるな危険。

Windows にあって Linux にない `\\.\COM10` みたいなパスを `Qt` 上で使うと Linux 非互換になっちゃいます。 `Qt` を使う以上は最初からそういうパスを扱わないよう/扱わなくて済むよう設計する必要がありそうです。

Comment: 大変よくわかりました。素早い回答ありがとうございます。