# ファイルパスの区切り文字が異なる結果で表示される

Tags: python, python3, pycharm

.pyファイル内に存在する、ある関数内で

```
print('__file__:    ', __file__)
```

というのをやったとき、開発環境のコンソールに出力される区切り文字（/または\）が違うのですが、この違いは何によって決まるのでしょうか？

```
__file__:     C:/・・<略>・・/file1.py
__file__:     C:\・・<略>・・\file2.py
```

※file1とfile2は同じフォルダ内に存在します。

**開発環境**
・パソコン：Windows 10 Pro (20H2 64bit)
・Python 3.9.7
・PyCharm 2021.3 (Community Edition)

よろしくお願いいたします。

### 追記

quickquipさん、コメントありがとうございます。

file1.py
では、

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi('PyCharm')
    print('__file__:    ', __file__)
    
    file2.Func()
```

感じになっていて、

file2.py
の中に、

```
def  Func():
    print('__file__:    ', __file__)
```

という具合になっています。なので、
`python file1.py` した時に中で `import file2` することででる `file2.py` の結果が `file1.py` のものと違うと言っている
に該当するだと思います。

Comment: 関連：[ディレクトリを取得すると、場合によっては、スラッシュとバックスラッシュが入り混じるのはどうしてでしょうか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/47709/19110)

Comment: python file1.py と python file2.py の結果が違うと言っているのか、python file1.py した時に中で import file2 することででる file2.py の結果が file1.py のものと違うと言っているのか、どちらでしょう（あるいはまた別で コマンドプロンプトとPyCharmで違う、とか?）

Comment: 古い記事ですが、PyCharm環境の影響かもしれません。[PyCharm file path separator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27418418/9014308) PyCharmではなく単独のPythonインタプリタで実行してみたら状況が変わるかもしれません。あとは`__file__`も変数なので読み込み時等に書き換えが行われている可能性も考えられます。[Why does my \_\_file\_\_ path contain both forward slashes and back slashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38799085/9014308)

Answer (score 1):

質問内容の環境とファイルをPyCharmの`Run`メニューの`Debug 'file1'`とか`Debug`で実行すると、質問の結果になります。

これをPyCharmの`Run`メニューの`Run 'file1'`とか`Run`で実行すると、パスの区切り文字は両方とも`\`で表示されますね。

PyCharmではない単独のPythonインタプリタで実行しても、パスの区切り文字は両方とも`\`に当たる半角の￥で表示されます。
PyCharmのTerminalウインドウで動作させても同様に両方とも`\`になりますね。

つまり**ファイルパスの区切り文字が異なる結果で表示される**のは**PyCharmのデバッグ実行で動作させているため**と考えられます。